# Regex: How to find a pattern on words of a certain length

Tags: regex

I am certainly not very experienced with regex but I've spent quite a while on this and I usually figure it out by now. I'm guessing someone else will have the answer right away, as my goal is very simple:

I need a simple regex to brute-singularize words (i.e remove -es or -s from the ends). The syntax for this is easy. What gets complicated is restricting it to words that are longer than 3 characters so that "US" doesn't become "U".

Here is what I am testing with:

childrens
horses
horse
bobs
us

which should match like so:

children**s**
hors**es**
horse
bob**s**
us

This is being done in a POSIX environment (Postgres) so that is also a bit restrictive.

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Regex alone can't do this.  While regex _can_ find all such words which might be candidates for replacement, the context would determine whether or not you do something.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: You need NLP (Natural Language Processing) to convert plural to singular in a reliable way. There are many NLP libraries available, such as https://pypi.org/project/inflect/

Comment: I am familiar with NLP but for my needs right now it doesn't have to be that exact. Thus the "brute-singularize" part in my description. But I fully agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
(?<=\w{3})(s|es)\b /i
```

Be advised that last `/i` is not part of regex, it's just case-insensitive flag. You also may want to add `g` and `m` flags to read entire string. Here is the breakdown:

- `(?<=\w{3})` - [positive `lookbehind`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), checking that there are 3 characters preceding the following pattern
- `(s|es)` - a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), looking for characters `s` or `es`
- `\b` - checking that end of a word follows right after the pattern.

Also be advised that this pattern does not differentiate words which ends with `s` in singular form (like proteus), and i'm very doubtful this task can be properly done by regular expression only.

Comment: thanks that works and is basically exactly what I came up with except I couldn't get the lookbehind working. Yours does work though. The only issue now is that Postgres is POSIX and as far as I can tell, that just means I have to adapt the code to: (?<=\w{3})(s|es)[[:>:]] to make it work..